# Drupal Site Fails (mostly) When Changing Nameservers

Tags: php, drupal, dns, hosting, drupal-6

I have an install of a Drupal 6 site, that is working great.  I'm in the midst of switching hosts to Company B, but still want to keep the domain registered from my old company, Company A.

I copied all of the files over to Company B, made the domain an add-on domain, copied the database, changed the settings.php file to point to the new database, then changed the nameservers to point to my new hosting company.

When the DNS change propagated through, the site came up, so it was hitting the correct folder, and the database was obviously working as well, but I got a spate of error messages (which I will include at the end) and the theme was completely non-existent.  I hurriedly changed the nameservers back, as this is a production site, and am now trying to figure out how it could have went wrong with an exact clone of all of the files. . .

The error messages I received:

```
* warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/sitename/public_html/public_html/modules/system/system.module on line 1020.
* warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/sitename/public_html/public_html/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
* warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sitename/public_html/public_html/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.

* warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/sitename/public_html/public_html/modules/system/system.module on line 1020.
* warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/sitename/public_html/public_html/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
* warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sitename/public_html/public_html/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
```

(I'm aware that the two public_html's are a little odd, it has to do with different naming conventions between the two hosts.  It does point to the same folder this way.)

Any ideas what I can do to get this site to work identically?

Thanks,
Terrik

Comment: I have the same Problem on my website, with exanctly the same error Message. Could you please specify how you exanctly fixed the problem? The Problem came up after changing the Domain name and installing a new Theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS changes can't break your site, they are just entries in an address book. It's got to be something to do with the way you copied the code and database over. Off the top of my head some things to check:

- You definitely copied all files. Sometimes on badly configured hosts if the webserver writes a file for you it can change the ownership of the file meaning you can't transfer it over FTP.
- Your theme doesn't include hard-coded links to your old domain (Clearing the site cache before copying, and on your production site might help too)
- Your new host has a PHP setup which clashes with Drupal. As a last resort, you could try installing a fresh copy of Drupal in a new subdomain to verify it operates correctly.

Comment: I might add, that sometimes, $base_url might be cached in drupal cache OR there is might be old URL in variables table. Especially this applies to multi-lingual sites.

Comment: @hfidgen  It was actually a combination of bullet points 2 and 3.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Terrik, what was the particular solution to this problem? I am having the same exact problems too.